# Undefined symbol in Apache HTTP Server

Tags: apache, http

When trying to make a proxy balancer work in my Oracle HTTP Server (based on Apache HTTP Server 2.2), I'm running into the following error, taken from the log file:

undefined symbol: ap_proxy_set_wstatus

It's a syntax error from the httpd.worker, and says that it cannot load the mod_proxy_balancer.so module into the server. Is this an issue where I need to re-download the module? Or is there something I need to add/edit in one of the configuration files?

Some more information:

- The balancer is running out of a VirtualHost, and directing traffic through 2 virtual hosts on another server.
- The following code (IP and port #s changed) is in a configuration file that is included in the httpd.conf file with the include statement:

>

```
Listen 1000

NameVirtualHost *:1000

<Proxy balancer://balancertest>
        BalancerMember http://ipaddress:0000
        BalancerMember http://ipaddress:0001
        lbmethod=bybusyness
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost *:7946>
        ProxyPass /texthere balancer://balancertest
        ProxyPassReverse /texthere balancer://balancertest
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It's not a configuration issue, but internal on the apache (or module) build. As such, it is a bug, and you could recompile them both for the correct possibly matching versions and see if that solves it, or file a bugreport with the maintainers if it doesn't.

Comment: Wrikken, thanks for the response. Do you know if there are instructions somewhere for recompiling the build and the module (I assume that's what you're talking about when you say "them")?

Comment: A recompile is just a compile, for [Apache the instructions are here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html), but I've idea what special things `Oracle HTTP Server` needs.